# Create grid vertically in java

Tags: java, netbeans-8, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am using GridLayout to make a grid one row at a time. I want to create such grid vertically and put an image in each grid. Here is my current code snippet. please give me some suggestions on how to proceed:

```
public ButtonGrid(int width, int length){

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout()); //set layout
        grid=new JLabel[length][width]; //allocate the size of grid
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream("I:\\cache1\\newtask_list.txt");
        bout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

        } catch (Exception e) {Logger.getLogger(ButtonGrid.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);}
        for(int y=0; y<length; y++){

                for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
                        BufferedImage image=null;
                    try {
                       str=bout.readLine();
                       str1=str.substring(0,23);

                       image=ImageIO.read(new File("I:\\cache1\\newtask\\"+str1));
                       } catch (IOException e) {Logger.getLogger(ButtonGrid.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                     }
                       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

                       grid[y][x]=new JLabel(icon); //creates new button 
                       grid[y][x]=new JLabel("("+x+","+y+")");
                       System.out.println(x+"\t"+y);
                       frame.add(grid[y][x]); //adds button to grid
          }

       }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonGrid(12,16);//makes new ButtonGrid with 2 parameters
}
```

Comment: Is it outputting at all? If so is it horizontal?

Comment: `grid[y][x]=new JLabel("("+x+","+y+")");` overwrites your new button.

Comment: Yup image is displaying at all but in a random way after reading from file. I want it to be displayed from top to bottom after reading from file. e.g. it will read first image and put on (0,0) then read second and put on (1,0) then read third and put on (2,0) then(3,0) then (4,0). After completing one column it will move on second column then do same as for for first column till all column. Is my logic not correct or there is some other way to do it. Please suggest.

Comment: You need to set the grid layout: GridLayout(X,Y) -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html you can then add a vertical grid.